Increase the Height or Padding of the ListView Header Row
I'm trying to increase the padding or height of the header row columns of a ListView. I've managed to change the background color and text color using this code.
SelsList.DrawColumnHeader += (sender, e) =>
{
    using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(64, 64, 122)))
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, e.Bounds);
    }
    e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Header.Text, e.Font, Brushes.White, e.Bounds);
    e.DrawDefault = false;
};

*SelsList is my ListView

I have used this code to increase the padding and height of the header row columns. But didn't work though. Is there are any other way to achieve this?
SelsList.DrawColumnHeader += (sender, e) =>
{
    using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(64, 64, 122)))
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, e.Bounds.Left, e.Bounds.Top, e.Bounds.Width, 50);
    }

    using (StringFormat format = new StringFormat())
    {
        format.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        format.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Header.Text, e.Font, Brushes.White, e.Bounds, format);
    }

    e.DrawDefault = false;
};


In order for SelsList.DrawColumnHeader to run, you must do the following settings first:
 SalesList.OwnerDraw = true;
 SalesList.View = View.Details;

The following link explains more:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.drawlistviewcolumnheadereventargs?view=windowsdesktop-8.0
Of course, my proposed method, which I will explain later, does not need to execute the mentioned event.
If you want to do this by creating a class that inherits from ListView, which I don't recommend, check out the link below:
Changing ListView Header and Grid Lines colors
Since changing the drawing functions for Windows form components is a bit complicated and requires careful attention to many undocumented issues, and on the other hand, there is no guarantee that it will work exactly right in future versions of Windows, so I do not recommend the above method.
It is also possible to change the height of data rows and not the height of the header by setting the list of images, which is explained in the following link:
C# Change ListView Item's/Row's height

But I have done it in a simpler way.
We hide the SelsList header and simulate the header by creating a new view list above it. Of course, in this method, drawing the header of the list will be simple.
Place the SelsList in a position on the form where there is enough space above it to increase the height of the header.
The codes are as follows:
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    static readonly Color HEADER_FORECOLOR = Color.Yellow;
    static readonly Color HEADER_BACKCOLOR = Color.FromArgb(64, 64, 122);
    const int HEADER_HEIGHT = 70;               
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetListView(HEADER_FORECOLOR, HEADER_BACKCOLOR, HEADER_HEIGHT, SelsList, this);
    }
    public static void SetListView(Color HeaderForeColor, Color HeaderBackColor, int HeaderHeight, ListView MainListView, Form MainForm)
    {
        // Create listViewHeader:

        var listViewHeader = new ListView
        {
            Name = "listViewHeader",
            Width = MainListView.Width,
            Height = HeaderHeight,
            GridLines = true,
            OwnerDraw = false,
            View = View.Details,
            HeaderStyle = ColumnHeaderStyle.None,
            BackColor = HeaderBackColor,
            ForeColor = HeaderForeColor,
            Location = new Point(MainListView.Location.X, MainListView.Location.Y - HeaderHeight)
        };

        // Set columns height in listViewHeader:

        var imgList = new ImageList
        {
            ImageSize = new Size(1, HeaderHeight)
        };
        listViewHeader.SmallImageList = imgList;

        MainForm.Controls.Add(listViewHeader);

        // Show grid lines and hide header row in the main list view (MainListView):

        MainListView.GridLines = true;
        MainListView.HeaderStyle = ColumnHeaderStyle.None;

        // Copy header columns as the first row to the listViewHeader:

        var IsFirstColumn = true;
        foreach (ColumnHeader Header in MainListView.Columns)
        {
            listViewHeader.Columns.Add("", Header.Width, Header.TextAlign);
            if (IsFirstColumn)
            {
                IsFirstColumn = false;
                listViewHeader.Items.Add(Header.Text);
            }
            else
                listViewHeader.Items[0].SubItems.Add(Header.Text);
        }
    }
}

Image of output is same as below:

